# How to express the following statement in $CTL^*$

Tags: proof-verification, logic

How to express the following statement in $CTL^*$:

"Between the events $q$ and $r$, event $p$ is never true."

So the path is something like this: $$\dots, q, \neg p,\neg p,\neg p,\neg p, r, \dots$$

or

$$\dots, r, \neg p,\neg p,\neg p,\neg p, q, \dots$$

By the way, when either $q$ or $r$ is true, $p$ can be true.

My conjecture: $[\textbf{AG}(q\to\neg\textbf{EF}(p\land\textbf{EF}r))]\land[\textbf{AG}(r\to\neg\textbf{EF}(p\land\textbf{EF}q))].$

It says that, when we meet a $q$ or $r$, in the future there is no way $p$ can become true with $\textbf{EF}r$ or $\textbf{EF}q$.

Can somebody provides some suggestions?

Ref: [Computation tree logic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible translation is

$$ \operatorname{\mathsf{AG}} (q \rightarrow \operatorname{\mathsf{A}} \neg p \operatorname{\mathsf{W}} r) \enspace, $$

where $\operatorname{\mathsf{W}}$ is the *weak until* operator.  The formula holds at a state $s$ if every path departing from every state $s'$ reachable from $s$ satisfies $\neg p$ until a state that satisfies $r$ is reached.

I'm assuming that it's OK for $r$ to never occur on some (or all) paths of the computation tree, as long as $p$ never occurs either.  If $r$ must occur, then the *strong until* $\operatorname{\mathsf{U}}$ is in order.

In any case, we stay within CTL, without the star.

Comment: I don't know why this formula $\textbf{AG}(q\to\textbf A r\textbf R\neg p)$ holds when $q,r$ and $p$ all are true. $r\textbf R\neg p$ means $\neg p$ should hold until $r$ is true(and the time $r$ is true, $\neg p$ should still hold) or $\neg p$ should hold forever if $r$ never become true.

Comment: What about $r$?  Is it necessary that it happens?  Or is a path where $\neg p$ continues to hold OK?

Comment: The problem doesn't specify if $r$ is necessary to happen. But I think it's okay that $\neg p$ continues to hold.

Comment: Sorry again!!! I found that when either $q$ or $r$ is true, $p$ can be true! I've corrected the specs, it's now more specific. Thank you very much!

Comment: OK. I'll revise.  But notice that your edit to the question has changed things in another important way.  Now we are also looking at what happens between $r$ and $q$.  Is it possible for $q$ to follow $q$ without intervening $r$'s?

Comment: The problem doesn't give the constraint, so I think is possible. 
The whole problem in the textbook says: "Express the following properties in CTL and LTL whenever possible. If neither is possible, try to express the property in CTL*:"

Comment: It's difficult to avoid ambiguity when using natural languages.  With that in mind, in my opinion the most likely interpretation of "Between the events $q$ and $r$, event $p$ is never true" is the one based on the weak until above.  In particular, the formula assumes that $q$ comes before $r$, if the latter occurs at all.